# Force user to supply a generic type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

Currently using apollo's new hook for React,

```js
const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(GET_CUSTOMERS);
```

in a TypeScript repo. Despite having `noImplicitAny` activated, the above function call produces no type error. Is it possible to force users to supply types for functions with generics?

Comment: I believe this addresses your question. It looks like `useQuery` already has two optional type arguments. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/static-typing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume noImplicitAny doesn't throw because GET_CUSTOMERS adheres to the argument's type. The generics are only used for casting.

Function signature: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/

```
function useQuery<TData = any, TVariables = OperationVariables>(query: DocumentNode, options?: QueryHookOptions<TData, TVariables>,): QueryResult<TData, TVariables> {}
```

If you want to enforce an interface of your own, you can wrap the function and specify the generic.

```
type T = AClass | MyInterface | ect;
const myUseQuery = (a: T, ...) => useQuery<T, ...>(a, ...);
```